# Does the condition of weapons affect gameplay?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Some weapons that were introduced in the [last update](http://blog.counter-strike.net/armsdeal/) (cosmetic) feature different kinds of weapon skins, all really neat, in my opinion.

Some of the qualities range from [Field-Tested](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/M4A4%20%7C%20Jungle%20Tiger%20%28Field-Tested%29), [Battle Scarred](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Sawed-Off%20%7C%20Irradiated%20Alert%20%28Battle-Scarred%29), [Factory New](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Sawed-Off%20%7C%20Irradiated%20Alert%20%28Factory%20New%29), [Minimal Wear](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/MP7%20%7C%20Whiteout%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29), even to [Well-Worn](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/SG%20553%20%7C%20Tornado%20%28Well-Worn%29).

Question is, do these affect gameplay? I'm pretty "poor", so I don't really have money to just throw on keys, and I'd like to know whether or not it's just a cosmetic look, or gives a slight battlefield advantage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in the latest patch "Arms Deal" is cosmetic. Including the qualities range. A bit of flavour text I suspect, or a way of determining rarity.

> **Q: Can I buy items that will affect gameplay and give me an advantage?**
>   A: No. All of the items are purely cosmetic.

You could argue that having a bright pink gun might put you at a disadvantage unless you are playing in happy candy fun land (I know it doesn't exist (yet!)).

The [Valve FAQ](http://blog.counter-strike.net/armsdeal/faq.php) released for this patch is worth a read.

Comment: 'til Valve adds Pyrovision to CS:GO, I guess we won't be seeing much happy candy fun land yet :D.

Comment: And does the quality change anything? Like will your skin ever "Wear off"?

Answer (score 0):

Weapons skins are "Vanity" And for looks only. However you can chose between an M4A4 and M4A1 skin for example. Each have their slight advantages and disadvantages. But switching from a "minimal wear" version to a "well worn" version does nothing but change the way it looks when you are playing. It will look beat up, but function the same.

Comment: Please try to avoid adding answers which just duplicate already posted answers without adding any new information.